# Changing bin width default in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to compare the distribution of a variable using frequency and percentages histograms. In other words I would like to see how many percentages each bin in frequency histogram represents.

```
#load data
j<-as.data.frame(Nile)
#frequency plot  
 ggplot(j, aes(x = x))+
 geom_histogram( fill = "black", binwidth = 200, alpha=0.8)+
 scale_x_continuous(breaks =seq(400,1400,200))
```

[image]
Next I try to create the percentage histogram with the same binwidth

```
#percentage plot
ggplot(j, aes(x = x), fill = "black", binwidth = 200, alpha=0.8)+
  geom_histogram( aes(y= (..count..)/sum(..count..)*100))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks =seq(400,1400,200))+
  ylab("Percentages")
```

However, it gives me an warning `stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.` with a different histogram that I expect
[image]

I tried the following

```
ggplot(j, aes(x = x), fill = "black", alpha=0.8)+
  geom_histogram( aes(y= (..count..)/sum(..count..)*100))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks =seq(400,1400,200))+
  ylab("Percentages") +
    stat_bin(bindwidth=200)
```

However, I get the same second histogram with default binwidth and the same warning

Comment: You can give `binwidth` (careful of the spelling) to `geom_histogram` which will automatically pass it to `stat_bin` - you don't need to explicitly add the `stat_bin`.

Comment: So, was incorrect spelling of `binwidth` the culprit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You spelled `binwidth` incorrectly. You spelled it as `bindwidth`

```
ggplot(j, aes(x = x), fill = "black", alpha=0.8)+
        geom_histogram(aes(y= (..count..)/sum(..count..)*100), binwidth = 200) +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks =seq(400,1400,200)) +
        ylab("Percentages")
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10529483)

Comment: Edited to address review critique

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a syntax error. Properly spelling binwidth will fix.